# How to get logger Hierarchy in Log4j2 ? I am migrating from Log4j1 to log4j2. Earlier we were using the Hierarchy Class to get the Hierarchy

Tags: log4j, log4j2

Earlier we were doing like below :
This is code we had used to get the logger hierarchy and loggers. but now in log4j2 the Hierarchy class does not exist.
What is the alternative to achieve below in log4j2 ?

```
public class ReportHierarchy extends Hierarchy
{
    public ReportHierarchy(Logger root)
    {
        super(root);
    }

    public Logger getLogger(String name)
    {
        return getLogger(name, defaultFactory);
    }

    private LoggerFactory defaultFactory = new ReportFactory();
}
```

We are using the ReportHierarchy class like below :

```
static
    {
        ReportHierarchy h = new ReportHierarchy(new RootLogger(Level.DEBUG));
        LogManager.setRepositorySelector(new DefaultRepositorySelector(h), "nuova");
        LogManager.resetConfiguration();
        NuRollingFileAppender.initializeCleanupTimer();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This part of architecture has not changed between Log4j 1.x and Log4j2, but the names changed. So you have:

- a [`ContextSelector`](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-core/apidocs/org/apache/logging/log4j/core/selector/ContextSelector.html) instead of a [`RepositorySelector`](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/spi/RepositorySelector.html),
- a [`LoggerContext`](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-core/apidocs/org/apache/logging/log4j/core/LoggerContext.html) instead of [`Hierarchy`](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/Hierarchy.html).

You don't need to set the `ContextSelector` in code any more, just set the `log4j2.contextSelector` [Log4j2 system property](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html#SystemProperties) to the fully qualified class name of your selector. You can do it e.g. in a `log4j2.component.properties` file.